# Matlab function numjac

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have a `function` defined as

```
F = model(t,y,X)
```

Where `y` are the variables and `X` represents some extra parameters I feed to the function. I have used [`numjac`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47204-fuzzy-model-identification-for-control/content/A3_Distill/numjac.m), with great success, to calculate `dF/dy`.
Can `numjac` calculate the Jacobian also with respect to the parameters `X`?

Comment: Why not use the MATLAB `numjac` rather than this version from the File Exchange? They are not the same, and the FEX version appears to be a modified version of the MATLAB implementation. I'm not nearly good enough at numerical analysis to tell whether the modifications are good ones or not, but I believe the MATLAB `numjac` is already pretty good. It may be that the FEX versions has some changes that benefit the FEX application (Fuzzy model identification) but wouldn't benefit yours.

Comment: @SamRoberts I am using `numjac`directly from MATLAB.

Comment: I understand that you're using a command `numjac` directly from MATLAB. But you linked to a file `numjac` that is available for download from the File Exchange. There is also a command `numjac` that is supplied as part of MATLAB itself, as part of the product. I was questioning why you're using the File Exchange command rather than the command supplied with MATLAB itself. The `numjac` on the File Exchange appears to be a modification of the `numjac` supplied with the product, and may be worse/slower (or better, I don't really know).

Comment: PS to make sure you know which command you're calling, and which versions you have available, type `which -all numjac`. You should probably see both your File Exchange command, and also the one supplied with MATLAB, which is typically in `\toolbox\matlab\funfun\numjac.m`.

Answer (score 2):

WHat about just appending the parameters 'X' to the vector 'y'?

Comment: I thought the function was going to give problems with a Nv+1 input and an Nv output... But it seems to be working!
One more thing, do you have any ideas on how to speed it up?